# Finding a rational point of large height on an elliptic curve knowing a real approximation

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms, diophantine-approximation

Let $y^2=x(x^2+n)$ be an elliptic curve with $n\in\Bbb Z$ (the same question can of course
be asked for a general e.c). I know (e.g. it has rank 1) that there exists a nontrivial
rational point $(r,s)$ with $r=p/q$, probably of large height. On the other hand I have an algorithm
(Heegner, Monsky,...) which can give me a real approximation $\alpha$ to $r$ to any accuracy I want. Is there any nontrivial way to search for $r$ ? The method I use for now
is to compute the convergents $p_n/q_n$ of the continued fraction of $\alpha$ and test if it is
on the e.c. If not, I increase the accuracy until it succeeds. It will of course eventually succeed, but in practice I need a much higher accuracy than the height of $r$ would suggest, typically 4 times or 8 times more.